# How do I add exceptions/constraints to this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, constraints

In this code, it translates a 24-hour time to a 12-hour time.

How would I disallow numbers that don't make sense? Ex: 25:60:60/3495:3413:3144

The hours shouldn't be over 24, and the minutes/seconds shouldn't be over 59

```
`# Python program to convert time from 24 hour
# to 12 hour format
 
# Convert Function which takes in
# 24hour time and convert it to
# 12 hour format
def convert12(str):
 
    # Get Hours
    h1 = ord(str[0]) - ord('0')
    h2 = ord(str[1]) - ord('0')
 
    hh = h1 * 10 + h2
 
    # Finding out the Meridien of time
    # ie. AM or PM
    Meridien=""
    if (hh < 12):
        Meridien = "AM"
    else:
        Meridien = "PM"
 
    hh %= 12
 
    # Handle 00 and 12 case separately
    if (hh == 0):
        print("12", end = "")
 
        # Printing minutes and seconds
        for i in range(2, 8):
            print(str[i], end = "")
 
    else:
        print(hh,end="")
         
        # Printing minutes and seconds
        for i in range(2, 8):
            print(str[i], end = "")
 
    # After time is printed
    # cout Meridien
    print(" " + Meridien)
 
# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # 24 hour format
    str = input(str("Please enter the time, in format 00:00:00: "))
    convert12(str)
`
```

I've tried things like,
if "25" in str:

Comment: You can always use assert (https://realpython.com/python-assert-statement/), f.e assert hh > 24

Comment: Hint: a function named convert should probably return something... ;-) Use the `re` module to parse the input, the `int(..)` function to convert from string to int, and the `divmod(..)` function to do the division and modulo at the same time.

Comment: `assert` statements can be disabled at runtime. Use them for testing, not validation.  `assert cond, msg` is equivalent to `if not cond: raise AssertionError(msg)`, so you can always use the same `if` statement but raise a different exception to indicate the problem you've discovered.